# How to make a variable to act as a upper bound on a summation constraint

Tags: linear-programming, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming

I have an integer variable, `M` which can take a value from `1, 2, .. 10`. Now, I want to use this variable as upper bound on a summation. For example, if during the solve the value of `M` resolves to `5`, then I want to take summation of first `5` elements of another list say, `P`. Where `P` is given to us.

So essentially, if `M` changes dynamically during the solve, I want to calculate and put a constraint on below:

```
sum{i from 1 to M} P_i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce intermediary variables : `y_i`. Please look at the below code listing, I have used Google-OR-tool for illustration.

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

s = pywraplp.Solver("", pywraplp.Solver.SCIP_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

M = s.IntVar(1, 10, name="")
y = {}
for i in range(1, 11):
    y[i] = s.BoolVar("")

# fixing M to be 5 to test the logic
s.Add(M == 5)

# below constraints will ensure that y_1 = y_2 = y_3 = y_4 = y_5 = 1
# and remaining y_i are 0
s.Add(sum(y[i] for i in range(1, 11)) == M)
for i in range(1, 11):
    s.Add(i * y[i] <= M)

s.Solve()

{i: y[i].SolutionValue() for i in range(1, 11)}
```

Above results in `{1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 0.0, 10: 0.0}`

Now you can use `y_i` to express:

```
s.Add(sum(y[i] * p[i] for i in range(1, 11)) >= x)
```

`x` is a placeholder